# How to use pivot in two or more columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample table

```
Item          Stocks         Sold           Year
------------------------------------------------------
Shoes            30             5           2018
Slippers         15            15           2019
Sandals          20            10           2016
Pants            25             5           2018
Shoes            20             0           2017
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the columns of `Stocks` and `Sold` will be posted by `Year`.

Example output :-

```
           As of 2016  |   As of 2017  |  As of 2018   |   As of 2019
----------------+------+--------+------+--------+------+---------+-------
Item     Stocks | Sold | Stocks | Sold | Stocks | Sold |  Stocks | Sold
----------------+------+--------+------+--------+------+---------+--------
Shoes           |      |     20 |    0 |     30 |    5 |         |
Slippers        |      |        |      |        |      |      15 |   15
Sandals      20 |   10 |        |      |        |      |         |
Pants           |      |        |      |     25 |    5 |         |
```

Glad for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
    declare @Stock nvarchar(max)
     (Select @Stock = Stuff( (select distinct ',[Stock_' + cast(year as varchar(5)) + ']' from Stock for xml path('')), 1,1,''))

    declare @Sold nvarchar(max)
     (Select @Sold = Stuff( (select distinct ',[Sold_' + cast(year as varchar(5)) + ']' from Stock for xml path('')), 1,1,''))

    declare @col1 nvarchar(max)
     (Select @col1 = Stuff( (select distinct ',cts.[Stock_' + cast(year as varchar(5)) + ']' + ',ctd.[Sold_' + cast(year as varchar(5)) + ']' from Stock for xml path('')), 1,1,''))


    declare @query nvarchar(max) = '
    ; with cte as (
    select Item, stock, ''Stock'' + ''_'' + Cast(year as varchar(10)) as colstock from stock)
    , ct as (
    select Item, Sold, ''Sold'' + ''_'' + Cast(year as varchar(10)) as colsold from stock)
    , ctstock as (
    select * from  
    ( select item, stock, colstock from cte )
    as d
    pivot 
    ( max(stock) for colstock in (' + @Stock + ') )
    as p
    ) 
    , ctsold as (
    select * from  
    ( select item, sold, colsold from ct )
    as d
    pivot 
    ( max(sold) for colsold in (' + @Sold + ') )
    as p
    ) 
    select cts.item, ' + @col1 + ' from ctstock as cts inner join ctsold as ctd on cts.item = ctd.item'

    exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: i'll check it mate..tnx :)

Comment: @YoyieGuangco Mark it as accepted if works for you, otherwise revert back for same.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregate

```
SELECT Item,
       SUM (CASE WHEN Year = 2016 THEN Stocks END) as Stock2016,
       SUM (CASE WHEN Year = 2016 THEN Sold   END) as Sold2016
FROM   yourtable
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: what if i got 20 or more years ?

Comment: use `Dynamic SQL` Do a search on that, there are lots of reference on this site